# Cleanup empty categories from category tree

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have created a category tree where each category contains sub-categories and each category contains its associated content. Some of the categories in this tree contain sub-categories but have no associated content. How can I clean up the category tree so that the tree structure contains only categories that have associated content, or that have sub-categories that have associated content? That is, in the category tree only paths should exist that lead to a category that has associated content.

The structure I have is an array:

```
[uid_of_category]
   => (array)content
      => empty
   => (array)sub_categories
      => [uid_of_category]
         => (array)content
             => empty
         => (array)sub_categories
      => [uid_of_category]
         => (array)content
             => [...associated content...]
         => (array)sub_categories
 [uid_of_category]
   => (array)content
      => empty
   => (array)sub_categories
      => [uid_of_category]
         => (array)content
             => [...associated content...]
         => (array)sub_categories
      => [uid_of_category]
         => (array)content
             => empty
         => (array)sub_categories
            => [uid_of_category]
               => (array)content
                 => [...associated content...]
            => (array)sub_categories
               ...
```

I tried to use a recursive function to get down to the lowest elements of the tree, but I don't know how to implement that even those elements remain in the tree that have no associated content, but whose sub-element has associated content.

Comment: Show some code, what have you tried? Is the category structure an array... More info needed.

Comment: Can you please post a **var_dump()** of an example array?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, recursion will help. But let use two functions instead of one. We will use one function to determine if a category meets the conditions to be cleaned (deleted). An another function to do the clean. In this function, the param will be passed by reference (&$categories). All of this assuming the structure is an array.

```
cleanCategories($categories);

function cleanCategories(&$categories)
{
    foreach ($categories as $key=>&$category) {
        if (isCleanable($category)) {
            unset($categories[$key]);
        } else {
            cleanCategories($category['sub_categories']);
        }
    }
}

function isCleanable($category)
{
    if (!empty($category['content'])) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($category['sub_categories'] as $category) {
        if (!isCleanable($category)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

From this approach, you can do a better, more effient solution.

And don't forget Stack Overflow is not a writting code service. You must think by yourself, think again, find a way (just thinking), put it in code, try the code, debug the code...

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in **isCleanable**: sub_categies

Comment: @lukas.j Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: You need an extra `&` somewhere.

Comment: @SalmanA Your edit is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to build an array based on the OP's post:

```
$arr = [
    "uid_of_category_0" => [
        "content"        => [],
        "sub_categories" => [
            "uid_of_category_0_0" => [
                "content"        => [],
                "sub_categories" => []
            ],
            "uid_of_category_0_1" => [
                "content"        => [
                    "associated_content_0_1_0",
                    "associated_content_0_1_1",
                    "associated_content_0_1_2"
                ],
                "sub_categories" => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "uid_of_category_1" => [
        "content"        => [],
        "sub_categories" => [
            "uid_of_category_1_0" => [
                "content"        => [
                    "associated_content_1_0_0",
                    "associated_content_1_0_1",
                    "associated_content_1_0_2"
                ],
                "sub_categories" => []
            ],
            "uid_of_category_1_1" => [
                "content"        => [],
                "sub_categories" => [
                    "uid_of_category_1_1_0" => [
                        "content"        => [
                            "associated_content_1_1_0_0",
                            "associated_content_1_1_0_1",
                            "associated_content_1_1_0_2"
                        ],
                        "sub_categories" => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

This would be the code to unset all empty arrays within $arr:

```
function unset_empty_arrays(array $arr): array {
  foreach (array_keys($arr) as $key) {
    if (is_array($arr[$key])) {
      $arr[$key] = unset_empty_arrays($arr[$key]);
    }
    if ($arr[$key] === [] && $key === 'sub_categories') {
      unset($arr[$key]);
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}

print_r(unset_empty_arrays($arr));
```

Edit: added *&& $key === 'sub_categories'*

Comment: That doesn't do what the question is asking for. Or it's unclear.

Comment: You are right, after re-reading the post I think that 'content' arrays should  not be removed, empty or not. I just adjusted the code, but might still be mis-understanding the post.

Answer (score 0):

This case is best solved with postorder traversal of tree.

In postorder traversal you want to do recursion over all sub-trees first. Then do required operation on the current node.

```php
function cleanUp(&$categories) {
    if (empty($categories)) {
        //no categories, nothing to do here
        return;
    }

    foreach ($categories as $key => &$category) {
        //first clean up sub categories
        cleanUp($category['sub_categories']);
 
        if (empty($category['sub_categories']) && empty($category['content'])) {
            //If there are no sub_categories left and there is no content remove category
            unset($categories[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

After doing clean up on sub categories, you know that if there are any sub categories left, they must have content or sub categories with content. So, at that point you can easily decide if current category needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your request, you have a tree and you want to clean it so as no branch without leaf remains in it.

In that case, I would like to propose a generic solution, working no matter the key names you chose. This solution is based on [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) functions. The first one allowing to walk the tree (or the branch) and the second one allowing to count the number of leafs in a tree (or branch), no matter the number of dimensions in it.

Here is a proposition:

```
function cleanTree($tree, $cleanTree = []) {

    // Walk the tree
    array_walk($tree, function ($branch, $node) use (&$cleanTree) {

        // Here is a leaf (the lowest element in the tree), we keep it
        if (!is_array($branch)) {
            $cleanTree[$node] = $branch;

        // Here is a branch that may contain some leafs
        } else {

            // Count the leafs of this branch
            $leafs = 0;
            array_walk_recursive($branch, function () use (&$leafs) { $leafs++; });

            // There is at least one leaf on this branch, so we walk it
            if ($leafs) {
                $cleanTree[$node] = cleanTree($branch);
            }
        }

    });

    return $cleanTree;

}
```

Using this function, all the branches without leaf are not kept.

Declare your tree as an array then clean it:

```
$myTree = [...];
$myCleanTree = cleanTree($myTree);
```

I tried it with the array sample provided by @lukas.j (thank you for this effort) and it worked.